# Python How to sort multi index Columns in Dataframe at different levels?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to sort the multi index columns at level 1 of a dataframe df

```
            |05/12/2020                 |05/13/2020
Created By  |Accuracy   Achieved %      |Accuracy   Achieved %
------------------------------------------------------------------
John        |  90        105            |   85       105
```

I want to sort the columns in level 1 as Achieved % & Accuracy instead of Accuracy and Achieved %

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer :)

Used sort_index

`pivot = pivot.sort_index(level=1, axis=1, sort_remaining=False, ascending=False)
pivot = pivot.sort_index(level=0, axis=1, sort_remaining=False, ascending=True)`

Doc : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sortlevel.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your DataFrame is in *df*, you can do it with the
following **single** instruction:

```
df = df.reindex(columns=df.columns.sortlevel([0, 1],ascending=[True, False])[0])
```

You can specify sort levels and order (for the levels given),
passing **lists** as respective parameters.

The trailing `[0]` is needed, because *sortlevel* returns a **tuple**
*(sorted_index, indexer)*, but we need only the sorted index.